# Iterate on a list coming from a variable

Tags: loops, pgffor

I'd like to iterate over a list of values, which is stored inside a variable.

The problem is that the list of items (`\myList` in the MWE) to iterate over is the value of a previously-declared variable (`\mydata`).

This nested declaration breaks the iteration, as shown in the MWE. Indeed, iterating over `\myData` does not give any problems while iterating over `\myList` does.

[image: MWE output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\def\myData{1,2}
\def\myList{\myData}

\begin{document}
\section*{Variables}

Mydata : \myData

Mylist : \myList

\section*{Iteration over myList} 
Somewhere this is broken due to the variable declaration...

\foreach \x in \myList
{
    Item \x \\
}

\section*{Iteration over myData}

\foreach \x in \myData
{
    Item \x \\
}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the variable re-definition not break the iteration ?
I cannot do otherwise since this MWE is a excerpt of a much broader project.

Comment: What's the reason for doing `\def\myList{\myData}`? Are you perhaps merging more lists into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an expansion issue. If you use  `\edef\myList{\myData}` or `\edef\myList{\myData}` then your code will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\def\myData{1,2}
\edef\myList{\myData}

\begin{document}
\section*{Variables}

Mydata : \myData

Mylist : \myList

\section*{Iteration over myList}
Somewhere this is broken due to the variable declaration...

\foreach \x in \myList
{
    Item \x \\
}

\section*{Iteration over myData}

\foreach \x in \myData
{
    Item \x \\
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, and the fix is simple. What else ? Thanks ! :)